# Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless not public?

Tags: android, android-theme

I keep getting an error saying that `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Button.Borderless` is not public and so can't be used in my app. But the equivalent non-light version `@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Borderless` gives no such error and can be used. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases it is not safe to directly reference the `@android:style` (or `@android:drawable`) resources directly, as often times the Android developer team will not guarantee that these themes will remain consistent across different SDK versions. If eclipse is giving you an error saying that something is wrong, it's usually a better idea to just copy and paste the themes from the source code into your project instead, and reference them from there. That way you know it will always work, no matter what.

Comment: But I was to understand that the Holo themes are going to stay relatively consistent? Anyway, that is what I've done.